# Mean of, 'Save by thine own accord'

Tags: terminology, pronouns

I want to understand a prayer entitled 'Good Morning Lord' by Grace E. Easley. In the last stanza the words *thy* and *thine own* are used, ' No joy or pain is ever sent, save by *Thine own* accord, so in the shadow of *Thy* love, I say ...Good Morning Lord'. But since this a prayer to the Lord and both words are capitalized, does it mean by *his* doing or by my own doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The prayer is addressed to the the Lord, so the second person "Thy" refers to the Lord.  (That is most likely why the pronoun is capitalized.)

The prayer expresses the idea that the Lord is responsible for all joy and pain, and that the prayer is offered in the shadow of the Lord's love.

Thanks to Jasper Locke for pointing out that "thine" is a form of "thy" that is used before vowels.  The same used to happen to "my" as well:

- Mine eyes have seen the glory ... (= my eyes have seen ...)
- Drink to me only with thine eyes ... (= ... with your eyes ...)

Comment: I would like to note that thine is the possessive version used before vowel sounds in Middle and Early Modern English, so thine own (Middle/Early Modern English)=your own (contemporary English).

Comment: @JasperLocke thank you for noting that.  I have found exceptions to the "-ine before a vowel" rule (not that it's relevant here).  I'll add to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Thy is an archaic word for Your (see http://www.thefreedictionary.com/thy for example), and it is traditional in written English to capitalise pronouns when they refer to (the Christian) God.

In both instances the prayer is referring to God's works.

[Sorry, this would have been a comment to the above, better, answer but I haven't yet the reputation to comment only]